# Reset counter after button click

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, counter

In **DeleteTask**, I have a button used to delete the list if checkbox is checked in the listView.

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int itemCount = listview.getCount();
                for (int i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    SearchList search = adapter.getItem(i);
                    if (search.isSelected()) {
                        adapter.removeItem(i);
                        delete.setText("DELETE");
                        counter=0;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

In **DeleteAdapter**, it has a counter used to count the checked box and display the counter in `button`. Once the delete `button` is clicked, the counter suppose reset to 0 and only shows `DELETE` in  delete `button` setText.

```
 holder.ckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                        int getPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                        search.get(getPosition).setSelected(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                        checkBoxCounter ++;
                        delete.setText("DELETE"+""+"("+ checkBoxCounter +")");
                    } else
                    {
                        int getPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                        search.get(getPosition).setSelected(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                        checkBoxCounter--;
                        if (checkBoxCounter == 0) {
                            delete.setText("DELETE");
                        }
                        else {
                            delete.setText("DELETE" + "" + "(" + checkBoxCounter + ")");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

My problem now is when the delete button is clicked, it show 'DELETE', but when I check the checkBox, the counter did not reset. How to reset the counter ?

**Edit**

I have change the counter to checkBoxCounter, but still getting the same result !

```
 delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int itemCount = listview.getCount();
                for (int i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    SearchList search = adapter.getItem(i);
                    if (search.isSelected()) {
                        adapter.removeItem(i);
                        delete.setText("DELETE");
                        checkBoxCounter=0;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

> When I click `button` delete, the button shows `DELETE`. But, when I
>   press another checkbox again, the counter starts from the last set
>   value instead of 1.

Please help.

Here are part of my app screen shot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R954N.jpg

Comment: what do you mean by reset you are making counter = 0

Comment: You'll have to set the `checkBoxCounter` to `0` in delete onclick listener. Probably a typo you are updating `counter` value not `checkBoxCounter`.

Comment: @jiteshmohite Everytime the delete button is clicked, the button will setText 'DELETE'. It should always reset the counter to 0. But when I check the checkbox, the button setText  show `DELETE(3)`.

Comment: @UmaKanth I change the variable but the result still same. There are two different classes, the name of the variables have to be same ?

Comment: @UmaKanth sir,please check my post again

Comment: where do you set `holder.ckbox.setOnClickListener` and  `holder.ckbox.setOnClickListener` ? Are they in adapter class?

Comment: @mismanc yes,in adapter class

Comment: I wanted to ask `holder.ckbox.setOnClickListener` and `delete.setOnClickListener` sorry! Both in adapter class?

Comment: @mismanc no...`delete.setOnClickListener` is in DeleteTask .

Comment: @mismanc my problem solved. Thanks

Comment: u r welcome. If I were you, I would define the int in adapter and control just from there by functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there are two different classes, then add a method inside the adapter class to reset the counter.

May be like this:

1. Inside adapter class, add:

   ```
   public void resetCheckedCounter(){
       checkBoxCounter = 0;
   }
   ```
2. For the "Delete" button, add:

   ```
   adapter.resetCheckedCounter();
   ```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 4):

assign `checkBoxCounter = 0` Inside onClick() function.
and for safety purpose you can change code as bellow to avoid updating checkBoxCounter from some other part of the code.

```
 holder.ckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                        int getPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                        search.get(getPosition).setSelected(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                        checkBoxCounter ++;
                        delete.setText("DELETE"+""+"("+ checkBoxCounter +")");
                    } else
                    {
                        int getPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                        search.get(getPosition).setSelected(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                        checkBoxCounter--;
                        if (checkBoxCounter <= 0) {
                            delete.setText("DELETE");
                            checkBoxCounter = 0;
                        }
                        else {
                            delete.setText("DELETE" + "" + "(" + checkBoxCounter + ")");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: check my post again. Thx

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `counter = 0`  you need to do `checkBoxCounter = 0` inside delete click listener

Comment: I have changed counter to checkBoxCounter, but the result still same

Comment: is your variable is static if not make it static and used same variable during showing and updating counter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128698/discussion-between-jitesh-mohite-and-hoo).

Comment: @jiteshmohite I noticed you have been leaving a lot of comments asking the OP to accept answers. Please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-on for a discussion of this. On this question you really shouldn't be leaving such comments as the OP clearly knows how the system works.